# Displaying A File Using StringVar() // Tkinter Python 3.5

Tags: python, file, tkinter

In tkinter, python, I'm creating an info like text editor that uses `StringVar()` to display a file, also, with the use of entry and a button, I created a delete button, which deletes a certain line in a file. The problem I have is that the file does not delete the specified line and it does not update to show the file's contents. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("text")
root.geometry("700x700")

file = open(r"info.txt", "r") 
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

strd = StringVar()



def updatestr():
    fileread = open(r"info.txt", "r") 
    lines2 = fileread.readlines()
    strd.set("{}".format(lines2))
    root.after(1, updatestr)
    fileread.close()
updatestr()

lads = Label(root, textvariable=strd)
lads.pack()


blank = Label(root, text="")
blank.pack()
blank = Label(root, text="")
blank.pack()
blank = Label(root, text="")
blank.pack()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.configure(width=9)
entry.pack()

def DeleteEntry():
    global file
    file = open(r"info.txt", "w")
    global lines
    for line in lines:
        if line!="{}".format(entry.get())+"\n":
            file.write(line)
    file.close()

confent = Button(root, text="Delete", command=DeleteEntry)
confent.configure(width=7)
confent.pack()
```

Not sure why this is happening, so I'd appreciate some help :) 
Thanks

Comment: forgot to add mainloop() at the bottom

Comment: Not sure if relater to your error but are you aware that, first parameter of `after` method is in _miliseconds_? I mean, `foo.after(1, bar)` will call `bar` every 1 milisecond.

Comment: @Lafexlos yes I am aware of this, as I want it to update every millisecond.